# Need Google Script to send an email if specific data added to specific column

Tags: email, google-sheets

I have no background in programming, and am new to Google Scripts and Stack Overflow.

I'd like to create a Google script which automatically sends an email when the word "No" is added to a specific column in Google Sheets.

I have already created and tested the script which sends an email if "No" is added to my spreadsheet, however, I need this process to be automated so that my co-workers must not manually run the script each time.

I would be extremely grateful if anyone would be willing to write the code, or guide me in the right direction.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. "if anyone would be willing to write the code, or guide me in the right direction."... um, that's not really how Stack Overflow works. You need to do the ground-work to get started. That means reading their tutorials and trying things. Once you've tried and run into a problem, then ask a question specific to that problem. We'll try to help you fix that issue. We need to see a minimal example of your code that demonstrates the problem you're seeing, otherwise we have to imagine what you did in our heads, which rarely works correctly.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. I have in fact searched for a solution for 2+ hours and found no solutions which worked.

During my research, I also found tons of posts requesting code, and an equal amount of folks who provided the code for the OP; this is why I asked!

Comment: I understand that there are tons of posts asking for code along with answers providing it, but those are the outliers; The people answering weren't paying attention to the fact that the site-wide users have decided that such questions are undesirable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set up an 'On Edit' or 'Time Driven' trigger and that should automate it... No code needed.

Use the clock with a pointer icon to the left of the 'Run' icon in the script editor to access the trigger.

Comment: Thanks for the assistance Calvin! I had not seen the trigger menu until you mentioned it to me.

Unfortunately, I could not use the triggers in the way that I had intended. I created the following trigger:

onOpen--> from spreadsheet --> onEdit

I was hoping that this would automatically execute my script in the event that the spreadsheet was edited.

Comment: Here's my code:

    function getTitles() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(),
      sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Form Responses 1"),
      urls = sheet.getRange("I2:I").getValues(),
      row, len, titleList = [], newValues = [],
      response, doc, title;
    
  var found = false;
    

  for (row = 0, len = urls.length; row < len; row++) {
    if (urls[row] != 'no') {
      found = true;
    } else newValues.push([]);
  }

Comment: Logger.log('newValues ' + newValues);
  Logger.log('titleList ' + titleList);

  // SET NEW COLUMN VALUES ALL AT ONCE
 // sheet.getRange("H3").offset(0, 0, newValues.length).setValues(newValues);
    
    
    MailApp.sendEmail("emailadd", "It Worked!", "Success"); 
    
  return titleList; 
}

Comment: I'm confused why the trigger didn't work. Are you receiving an error? What happens when you try to run the script?

Comment: My process:
1. Created Google Form
2. Linked Google Form submissions to Google Sheets
3. Created the aforementioned script to send email when column "I" field reads "No"
4. Accessed "Script Editor" via spreadsheet
5. Accessed "Current Project's Triggers" 
6. Set values as "onOpen", "From Spreadsheet", "On Edit"
7. Saved script
8. Test: Submit form with "No" value entered in column "I" field.
9. No email is sent

Note that I could manually run the script from within the script editor and I would receive the desired email.

Comment: Thanks for going through the process. The part I'm confused about is how you set up the triggers. The triggers, onOpen and onEdit are separate from each other and you should have only been able to select one of these. Can you clarify what you did to set up the trigger... Possibly attach a screenshot if you can?

Comment: Sorry for my delayed response.

I have been hacking at this problem for a couple hours now, and the trigger is now working.

The problem was that I was running a function titled 'onOpen' when I should have been running the function 'getTitles'. I realized that the script that I copied used the title 'getTitles' rather than 'onOpen'. 

I appreciate your patience and assistance Calvin! Thanks!

Comment: No problem! I'm glad you figured it out. If my answer helped you, would you mind giving it a checkmark/up vote? Thanks!

Comment: It says that I require 15 reputation points in order to do so. Looks as if I need to become more active on here! 

I currently have "-1" due to the way I phrased my question. Fun times.

Comment: Yes. I will be sure to vote for your solution in the event that I ever earn the coveted Stack Overflow rep points. :)